# Is 'so less' proper English

Tags: chinese

I was wondering if saying 'so less' is proper English?
Example:
   "This pizza is so less"
   "They gave me so less squid rings"

Or maybe even 'so more'?
Example:
   "This burger is so more"

Comment: No. Those things are not proper English.

Comment: _Less_ and _more_ often go with _than_. What idea are you trying to express? That your pizza is smaller than someone else's?

Comment: Please complete the Tour (we can tell you haven’t) to find out who this site is for and why your question is unsuitable.

Comment: It would be fine *in context* if it were *so **much** less*. Since *much* is just an intensifier, I can think of no syntactical reason that *so less* is wrong; nonetheless, we simply don't say it.